# Activity resumed from notification before notification is handled

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

My notification needs to send a broadcast when clicked. The problem is that in one specific use case, clicking the notification first resumes the last activity the user was in and then sends the broadcast.

This behavior is only observed when the user pauses an activity by pressing the power button, receives a notification, wakes the screen with the power or home button and clicks the notification without unlocking the screen. In all other cases, the broadcast is sent, received and handled before any activity gets resumed.

In this case, the top-most activity on the back stack's onResume method is called before my broadcast is received.

I declare my receiver in the manifest like so:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.HANDLE_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.HANDLE_MESSAGE" />
... 
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.PushNotificationBroadcastHandler"
        android:permission="com.example.broadcasttest.HANDLE_MESSAGE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.broadcasttest.HANDLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I use a helper method to send a notification:

```
public static void sendNotification(String msg, Context context)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PushNotificationBroadcastHandler.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_HANDLE_NOTIFICATION);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(context.getApplicationInfo()))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

I've tried this both with a real push notification (which passes a ReceiverRestrictedContext, apparently) and a mock one sent with an Activity as the context.

It doesn't really matter what the BroadcastReceiver does in this case, the problem is that its onReceive method is being called only after the last activity's onResume.

So far, I've tried using `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of using `context` itself. I've also tried starting an activity instead of sending a broadcast, but that seems to have no effect on the problematic behavior. It's also not related to any app-specific code, I created a project just to test it (and provide code examples here), so I'm sure that the problem is either in these code snippets or in the Android OS itself.

Any input would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: try starting a service instead of sending broadcast and use getBaseContext() for context

Comment: Doesn't change anything, Rajesh.

Comment: hey try adding process tag to broadcast reciever in manifest file and set to some arbitrary value

Comment: Why would that work, exactly? Edit: tried it nonetheless, didn't work.